# How to get rid of text outline on JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm making a program which includes JButtons with the text "+" and "-" on them. Why does the JButton have an outline around the text within? How do I get rid of the square around the text for a cleaner look?

Image here shows the issue on the first red button.

[image: GUI image]

Comment: Did you try searching the _javadoc_ ? Maybe [setFocusPainted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setFocusPainted-boolean-) is what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `jbutton.setFocusPainted(false);` method.